# Can't connect to Sandbox for In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm working on an app with IAP. Code-wise, everything seems to be done. All my unit tests are passing, I get an instance of `SKProduct` from the AppStore, have a simple UI in place, etc.

When I try to make a purchase, I can see the standard *Sign In to iTunes Store* popup. Then, when I enter my test user's credentials, I'm asked for password again and again.

I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

P.S.

- I did logout from AppStore in Settings before trying it.
- I did confirm the e-mail address for test user.

Comment: Did you logout of the appstore in settings? Start your app and it will ask you to login again. Now login with your test account. Test account can be made in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned it in my question: "I did logout from AppStore in Settings before trying it."

Comment: Sorry mist that part. My only idea would then be that a real iTunes account already exists with the same e-mail adres. Could you try and create a new test account?

Comment: @rckoenes Impossible. I'm using `example.com` domain that is reserved for "illustrative examples in documents".

Comment: Hmmm, weird I've always used really e-mail address, (just used `+IAPTest` after the user part and had to always confirm my e-mail before I could log into any app.

Comment: @rckoenes So, I tried to create a new one with a real address. Then I confirmed it. When I try to log in, iOS keeps asking me to enter the password again and again. :(

Comment: @rckoenes I simplified the question. :)

Comment: It might be iTune connectivity problem. Please try after some time. I had face same problem many time.
Best Luck.

Comment: Did you login inside Settings or inside your running App? I had difficulties too, when I tried to login in the Settings. But once i logged out in Settings and then started my App and logged in inside my app, it suddenly worked.

Comment: @joern I'm doing it exactly as you do. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to downgrade the iOS to 7.0.4 (latest stable) and it solved my problem.